# sql query: pivot but with different count or rows

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

What is the best variant to construct query to collect rows into columns like pivot, but without aggregation and several rows may be in each column?

Sample data:

```
id, parent_fk, month, quantity
10, 1111, 'jan', 21
11, 1111, 'jan', 24
12, 1111, 'feb', 12

13, 2222, 'jan', 3 
14, 2222, 'feb', 4
15, 2222, 'mar', 5

16, 3333, 'feb', 77
17, 3333, 'feb', 88
16, 3333, 'mar', 99
```

Each month may contain different number of rows. I have to put them alongside and justify by heigths.
I'd like to show these data as:

```
parent_fk, jan, feb, mar
1111,    21, 12, __
1111,    24, __, __
2222,     3,  4,  5
3333,    __, 77, 99
3333,    __, 88, __
```

Currently I have such not-elegant query (create ordering inside each month with row_number over partition, and join all the monthes by this ordering):

```
select
    nvl(JAN.parent_fk, nvl(FEB.parent_fk, nvl(MAR.parent_fk, -1))) calc_parent_fk,
    JAN.quantity jan, 
    FEB.quantity feb, 
    MAR.quantity mar
 from
    (select id, parent_fk, quantity, 
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY parent_fk, mnth order by id) "RN" 
    from T_MONTH_DATA 
    where mnth = 'jan') JAN 
full join
    (select id, parent_fk, quantity, 
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY parent_fk, mnth order by id) "RN" 
    from T_MONTH_DATA 
    where mnth = 'feb') FEB
    on JAN.parent_fk = FEB.parent_fk and JAN.RN = FEB.RN
full join
    (select id, parent_fk, quantity, 
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY parent_fk, mnth order by id) "RN" 
    from T_MONTH_DATA 
    where mnth = 'mar') MAR
    on FEB.parent_fk = MAR.parent_fk and FEB.RN = MAR.RN
order by 1
```

Is there more simple way to present such data? 
How to get resulting parent_fk? (I use nested NVL, because I don't know which of the monthes contain max of rows, and all other monthes have null there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle 11g use `pivot` clause and function `row_number()` like this:

```
select parent_fk, jan, feb, mar 
  from ( 
    select row_number() over (partition by mnth, parent_fk order by id) rn, 
           parent_fk, mnth, quantity 
      from t_month_data )
  pivot (sum(quantity) for mnth in ('jan' jan, 'feb' feb, 'mar' mar))
  order by parent_fk
```

Test data and output:

```
create table t_month_data (id number(4), parent_fk number(4), 
                           mnth varchar2(3), quantity number(6));

insert into t_month_data values (10, 1111, 'jan', 21);
insert into t_month_data values (11, 1111, 'jan', 24);
insert into t_month_data values (12, 1111, 'feb', 12);
insert into t_month_data values (13, 2222, 'jan',  3);
insert into t_month_data values (14, 2222, 'feb',  4);
insert into t_month_data values (15, 2222, 'mar',  5);
insert into t_month_data values (16, 3333, 'feb', 77);
insert into t_month_data values (17, 3333, 'feb', 88);
insert into t_month_data values (16, 3333, 'mar', 99);

PARENT_FK        JAN        FEB        MAR
--------- ---------- ---------- ----------
     1111         21         12 
     1111         24            
     2222          3          4          5
     3333                    77         99
     3333                    88
```

Comment: Thank you, @Ponder Stibbons, very nice solution.

Additional question: if I have the input data in different tables (one for each month), how to join them horizontally?

Comment: Probably you need to union them all at first (`union all`). Rest is the same.